How do we consider kinetic or potential energy of earth while applying conservation of energy?
If we take a system while applying conservation of Mechanical Energy That contains earth by we neglect potential or kinetic energy of earth ?
Or what is the real concept?

What do you mean by the energy of the earth?

I don't get the question, either. Please try to reformulate your question.

What does "w,ext force" mean?

W,ext means work done by external force is zero and by energy of earth I just mean potential or kinetic energy of earth

By we ignore it during conservation of mechanical energy in a system containing earth

Since momentum is conserved, if the block has a change in momentum of
$$\Delta p =  m\Delta v $$
then so does the Earth (with a minus sign).
That means the Earth takes up an energy of:
$$ \Delta E = \frac{\Delta p^2}{2M_{\oplus}} $$
and since
$$ M_{\oplus} \gg m $$
we completely ignore it and never mention it again.
Note: 1) sorry for the typos. 2) sometimes we fixate on $KE = \frac 1 2mv^2$ (with good reasons), but in a lot of problems, $v$ is irrelevant, and it's best to use $KE =  p^2/2m$. It seems trivial, but it can change how you conceptualize a problem, for the better.

$\Delta{}p=m\Delta{}v$

$\Delta p = p_{final} - p_{initial} = (mv){final} - (mv){intial} $. Assuming mass is fixed, $\Delta p =mv_{final} - mv_{intial} = m(v_{final} - v_{intial}) \equiv m\Delta v $.

@stickynotememo oh dear, major screw up!

Happens to the best of us.
